# Why is it showing 'cant find the angular project' while dockerizing an angular project

Tags: angular, docker

I am trying to dockerize my angular app. 
I tried a pretty simple example and found some solutions.
But when I followed them I found that at the end it gives an error showing `' The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.'`

My docker file is :

```
FROM node:slim as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install 
COPY . .
EXPOSE 4200
CMD npm run start
```

My docker-compose file is :

```
version: '3'
services:
  angdockdemo:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "4242:4200" 
    volumes:
      - "/app/node_modules"
      - ".:/app"
```

I found out that the problem is in the docker-compose file while mapping the volume `".:/app"`. If I use a different folder to map like `".:/app2"` then everything works perfectly. But I didn't get any explanation why it was not working and why it is working when I mapped to a different folder.
Does anyone have any explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say:

```yaml
volumes:
  - "/app/node_modules"
  - ".:/app"
```

This does two things.  First, it overwrites the entire content of `/app` with whatever content happens to be in the directory holding the `docker-compose.yml` file; this may or may not match the code in the image.  Second, it mounts an anonymous volume on `/app/node_modules`; since you've told Docker this directory holds user data, Docker will refuse to every update it even if the `package.json` file changes.

When you change the mount points to `/app2` you're not overwriting the content in `/app` in the image, so your container is able to see the code the Dockerfile builds, and it ignores the mounted content (it has no reason to look in the `/app2` directory).  If changing this makes the application work, the host content doesn't match the image content and the bind mount is breaking the application.

I'd recommend just deleting these `volumes:` entirely, and using the code that's built into the image.  You can [install Node](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) on the host fairly easily if you need a live development environment.  A typical browser application won't have complex build-time dependencies and can't take advantage of Docker networking, so there's not a lot of benefit to running it in Docker.

Comment: Thanks @David Maze for the details. But why every other example are there on the internet where they used ".:/app" for mapping volume and in their case it was working. Why it was working in their case and why it is not working in my case ?

Comment: Another question, when i write  ".:/app", does dot(.) mean the current directory of local(host) system or the current directory of the docker image?

Comment: `.` on the left-hand side of the colon means the directory containing the `docker-compose.yml` file.  Be aware that `localhost` generally means "this container" in Docker land; both the host and container think that they are `localhost` but those `localhost`s are different.